# Timer в консольном приложении Java

Tags: java

Задумка следующая: я добавляю в БД запись, но перед этим хочу немного "проанимировать" процесс добавления, выводя в консоль последовательно значения: 10%...20%...30%... и т.д. до конца... в конце вывести слово "Добавлен!".
Каждый процент необходимо выводи с интервалом в секунду, т.е. сначала секунда без информации, потом через секунду вывести 10%..., еще через секунду 20%... и т.д.
Вроде все получается, но слово "Добавлен" вылетает уже в самом начале работы программы, да и вообще вся программа летит вперед своей жизнью совершенно не дожидаясь пока проработает до конца блок кода с таймером.
Поясните пожалуйста, как правильно записать, чтобы программа дождалась окончания работы в блоке таймера и только потом в зависимости от успешного или неуспешного добавления записи, проработала дальше.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class MyTimer{
public static int proc = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){

    final Timer writeTime = new Timer();
    writeTime.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run(){
            if(proc < 100) {
                proc = proc + 10;
                System.out.print(proc + "%...");
            }
        }
    },1000,1000);
    System.out.println("Добавлен"!);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `Timer` не принципиален

```
//создаем новый поток
    Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        // то что будет выполняться в потоке
        public void run() {  
            int proc = 0;
            while(proc < 100) {
                proc = proc + 10;
                System.out.print(proc + "%...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // задержка 1000 мс
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // можно в это место перенести вывод и убрать Thread.join(); тогда основной поток висеть не будет  
        }
    });
    //запускаем поток
    mThread.start();
    //подождем пока поток завершит свое исполнение 
    mThread.join();

    System.out.println("Добавлен");
```

Comment: Имхо, `for(int proc=0; proc <= 100; proc += 10)` вместо `while` красивее будет)

Comment: @Evgeniy, возможно, на вкус и цвет как говорится... Просто как то так сложилось, что циклы подобного рода (которые звучат как "делаю пока...") я оформляю через `while`

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогло! То что нужно!

Comment: @Victor, а с помощью таймера это можно сделать? Я запихал условия в метод run(), но не могу понять как заставить всю программу ждать пока выполнится таймер и только потом продолжать работу

Comment: @TimLeyden нет таймер не имеет возможности "повесить" основной поток пока выполняется сам, он для того и разработан что бы циклично выполнять код не загружая основной поток. Если же вы все таки хотите в таймере проделать это все придется сделать так: `if(proc < 100) {... } else System.out.println("Добавлен"); `. Это выведет вам "Добавлен" в нужный момент после выполнения таймера. И все что будет написано ниже объявления таймера - будет выполнятся без оглядки на таймер

Comment: @Victor, в принципе то, о чем вы сказали я первым делом и сделал, убедился что мне это не подходит и пришел сюда =) Надеялся, что таймер умеет это делать. В прочем ваша подсказка мне помогла, вопрос решился и спасибо вам за помощь :)